# how to add Add UIButton in a UIWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i have small doubt.. i am displaying uiwebview dynamically based on json response. i need to add uibutton in uiwebview. so i am adding uibutton in uiwebview. But the uibutton should display only first uiwebview. remaining webviews does not display uibutton.i took uiview as a superview. and uiwebview adding subview of uiview. and finally uibutton is adding subview of uiwebview .i am writing my code like this. help me any body..

```
UIView *view = (UIView *)[self.scrollView viewWithTag:[[response valueForKey:@"DatacardId"] integerValue]];

UIWebView *webview = (UIWebView *)[view viewWithTag:WEBVIEW_TAG];

//Enable/Disable previous and next button based on page index and pagecount

[self presentNextAndPreviousButtonsBasedOnResponse:response];

self.isCardsInitialization = TRUE;

button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button1 setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

button1.frame = CGRectMake(120.0, 50.0, 160.0, 40.0);

int index = (int)[[webview subviews] indexOfObject:button1];

NSLog(@"index value of button is:%d",index);

[self webViewDidFinishLoad:webview];

[webview addSubview:button1];
```

Comment: add [webView bringSubviewToFront:button1] in webViewDidFinish load delegate.

Comment: I have multiple doubts regarding your code. 1. Why are you calling `webViewDidFinishLoad:` manually? 2. Won't `int index = (int)[[webview subviews] indexOfObject:button1];` always return **NSNotFound** as the `button1` is not yet added to `webview` as a subview.

Comment: @UditS plz give me any idea.. i struck this thing past two hours.

Comment: @UditS this method is for finding button index value.. int index = (int)[[webview subviews] indexOfObject:button1];

Comment: Where are you calling this code? In `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` or somewhere else?

Comment: @UditS in viewDidLoad i am calling this method

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of your requirement:

1. You need to Add a button to your `UIWebView` only the first time it loads
2. On all future pages loaded on the `UIWebView`, the button should be removed
3. When user taps the Button, it should be removed
4. On every first load of the `UIWebView` based on json response, button should be displayed.

**Solution**

Add a `BOOL` variable in your class Extension to be used as a flag to determine if the button is to be displayed or not.

```
@property BOOL displayButton;
```

Set the `UIWebViewDelegate` and `displayButton` property in `viewDidLoad` and initialize the `UIButton`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *webview = (UIWebView *)[self.view viewWithTag:WEBVIEW_TAG];
    webview.delegate = self;

    if (!self.button1) {

        // Initialize the button
        self.button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.button1 setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        self.button1.frame = CGRectMake(120.0, 50.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    }

    _displayButton = YES;
}
```

By setting the delegate of your `webview`, you do not need to call `webViewDidFinishLoad:` manually as it will be called when the `webview` actually completes loading. (As it is designed to be)

In `webViewDidFinishLoad:`, you can add your `UIButton` if the `webview` is loaded for the first time, or remove the button if it is a subsequent load.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    if (_displayButton) {

        // Add the button to webview
        [webView addSubview:self.button1];

        // Set _displayButton to No, to avoid button being added in future loads
        _displayButton = NO;

    } else {

        // Remove the button
        [self.button1 removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

To remove the button when it is tapped just call `removeFromSuperview` in `aMethod` (selector added to the button on intialization)

```
- (void)aMethod {

    //Remove the button from superview when it is tapped
    [self.button1 removeFromSuperview];
}
```

You will need to set `_displayButton = YES;`, whenever you load a fresh response in `UIWebView`

Comment: i am displaying web view dynamically based on json response. for example in my json response having 5 uiwebviews, then i need to show unbutton for each web view. that is my requirement

Comment: In that case you can create the button in `viewDidLoad` and just add / remove it from webview as required. Check the updated answer.